# How alexa-app framework and jovo framework are different?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I have trying to build and looking for a framework for my web service end point and I came across two frameworks:
Alexa-app: https://github.com/alexa-js/alexa-app
Jovo: https://github.com/jovotech/jovo-framework-nodejs
Can some one share the difference between these two frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the founders here from [Jovo](https://www.jovo.tech/). Both frameworks have their advantages, but the main difference is for which platforms you can build.

- Alexa-App has been around for quite a while and is a great community-maintained project, completely focused on building for Amazon Alexa (as the name suggests)
- Jovo currently supports to build apps for both Amazon Alexa and Google Assistant (Google Home) with one code-base, and offers a lot of tools around that, like local prototyping

I feel like the best way is to try them out both and see what you like better. If you want to give Jovo a try, take a look at our recent [v1.0 launch announcement](https://medium.com/@einkoenig/our-biggest-update-ever-today-were-releasing-jovo-framework-v1-0-7783f39f1728).